# ASP.NET Nested Repeater Accessing elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a list of Accommodation objects bound to a Repeater, and then a nested Repeater which has the various attendee groups listed [e.g. Default, Seniors, Juniors]. This is all output fine, with the values displayed as LinkButtons, which when clicked gets sent to a code-behind event handler.

Here is an example of the output to give you a picture [with some er... interesting attendee group names]:
[The output from the nested Repeaters http://abunchofletters.co.uk/images/report-accommodation-section.png](http://abunchofletters.co.uk/images/report-accommodation-section.png)

In the event handler, I test the object parameter to see which Repeater has been sent, as the outer repeater's links can also be clicked [so the Accommodation would be set, but no Attendee Group].

**Is there a way to get a HiddenField from the outer RepeaterItem that contains the currently clicked inner repeater's LinkButton?** E.g. From the image, I click the Attending link in the Women section. So the EventArgs via FindControl can get me the hidden field which contains the Attendee Group's ID, which is good, but I also need the Accommodation ID [to know whether it was either Wimbledon Hotel Inn or New Acc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that all you need to do is access the **grand**-parent. I tried the parent already, but then realised that would only take you as far as the inner Repeater.

All that was needed was:

```
repeaterArgs.Item.Parent.Parent.FindControl( "hdnAccommodationID" ) as HiddenField;
```